# How to use ANRWatchDog with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, android-anr-dialog

My app occasionally produces an ANR so I've installed the nuget package Xamarin.ANRWatchDog in the hope of finding where the issues are coming from but I'm having problems using the package so I'm hoping someone that has used it before can assist me.

I've installed the package, and started it as suggested in the ReadMe file `new ANRWatchDog().Start();` (in OnCreate()).  I've turned off the setting that ignores debugging (just so that I can test the package) by adding `new ANRWatchDog().SetIgnoreDebugger(true).Start();` (in OnCreate()).

My hope was - running my app and getting it to hit a breakpoint, and then I was expecting some sort of listener to be fired as a result.

I'm not exactly sure what gets called during an ANR and where the stack trace can be found.

I've tried several things and cannot get it to work at all.

If someone has used this package, I would appreciate a helping hand getting this set up so that I can use it.

Cheers...

Comment: The default waiting time is five seconds. Have you made sure to wait for five seconds when the debugging is paused on a breakpoint and then also continued debugging? If you never continue debugging, there's no way for the watchdog to raise an exception that you would then catch. Also, could you check the output log whether you can see any lines with `ANR-WatchDog` in them?

Comment: To see it in action, just hang the UI/main thread with a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);`

Comment: Yes I have waiting several minutes and then allowed my app to continue. I can see several lines in the output log with "ANR-WatchDog" - some saying "ANR.WatchDog.dll not found".  Should I not be able to create a listener that gets called with an ANR so that I can do something with the error stack?

Comment: I've removed my breakpoint and added a long sleep (as suggested by @SushiHangover - after 5 seconds I can now see a message in the output log "An ANR was detected but ignored because the debugger is connected (you can prevent this with setIgnoreDebugger(true))".  So something is happening, but I have this set to true so not sure why it is still being ignored due to me debugging.